# Javascript - Disable URL in alert

Tags: javascript, ipad

On the iPad my `alert('hi')` pops up with a URL in the title zone.  Can I turn this URL off?  I do not want to see it.  I am considering using some jQuery plugin as a workaround, but it sure would be nice to just fix it.

Comment: @Diodeus - Its not random. I always see the URL of the current page in the alert popups on iPad. In the same area where one might expect to see "Windows Internet Explorer" on the IE version of the popup. Instead, you see `http://blahblah/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the title of a javascript alert box, for user security reasons.  You could use an alternative such as a pop-up `<div>`.

Comment: I was considering jQuery modal dialogues.   But these things require a lot of overhead and styling.  The styling options are not consistent with the company standard CSS.  So, it would be nice to avoid this option and be able to use the default stuff.  But, if its not possible...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that can be turned off, alerts are defined in the browser itself. You can redefine alert `(window.alert = jqueryAlertPLugin.alert)` and not have to worry about your code calling the native one. I recommend the jAlert plugin. You will lose the blocking functionality of the native alert, but I bet that isn't usually an issue for most people.